# iOS 10.3.1 update breaks some NSAttributedString properties?

Tags: nsmutableattributedstring, ios10.3

I'm going to ask and then answer my own question in the hope that this will help someone.

Our app used `NSMutableAttributedString` to define a strikethrough attribute for certain parts of our string.

```
    NSRange range = [fullString rangeOfString:product.originalDeal];
    [dealString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithSize:12] range:range];
    [dealString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:@1 range:range];
    [dealString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:range];
    [dealString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:range];
```

In iOS 10.3 we noticed that the strikethrough feature no longer occurred consistently. Sometimes it was present, other times it was absent.

**Question: How to get the strikethrough working again?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we fixed it:

```
    [dealString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(1) range:range];
```

at the bottom of our attributes listing. This overcame the issue in both iOS 10.3 and 10.2.

Note that if the string contains the element `\n` and the offset attribute range includes that element, it would also break (no strikethrough). We applied the offset to just the portion of the string to generate the strikethrough.

The other attributes - gray and font - were not affected.